# Is it possible to stream live video from ROS to a windows desktop?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im a noob at this so I apologize if my question is stupid. I want to use a 360 camera like the ricoh theta S (that would be mounted on a drone), connect it to the DJI manifold of a drone that would be running ROS, use a 4g dongle on the manifold to send the data to a desktop computer, and use the video from the 360 camera on a vr headset such as the gear vr or the oculus or any other. Is it possible? How easy or hard it is to do that? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242399/is-it-possible-to-stream-live-video-from-ros-to-a-windows-desktop-?/) by [potro777](https://answers.ros.org/users/27834/potro777/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it technically *is possible* but the video will have very very high latency (i.e. unusable). It looks like that camera has USB 2.0 which really isn't fast enough for HD video, but you could try simply using the [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) package to see things working. Also ROS uses TCP by default which is not good for transmitting large video over wireless, there is [UDPROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/UDPROS) that uses UDP instead, but I don't know how well it is supported.

I think in reality if you wanted to have a usable video feed, you would need special hardware like a [Connex Prosight from Amimon](http://www.getfpv.com/the-connex-prosight-hd-vision-kit.html) that connects to the camera's HDMI. I don't know much about DJI, there might be something on board the drone that does something similar like letting you send your own video over the Lightbridge link if it has one?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1